# "Site Stats" and "Help us Grow this Site" are missing

Tags: feature-request

Several Beta sites have "Site Stats" and "Help us Grow this Site" boxes on the right panel, i.e., the site launched before GenAI, has them:

[image: Site Stats and Help this site grow boxes]
<sup>Source: [Programming Language Design and Implementation Beta](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/)</sup>

[Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/), another SE site not having an Area 51 proposal also has these boxes.

Please add these boxes to GenAI SE homepage.

Comment: FWIW, I found this [link](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#newest) that can track such information.